# Round-robin table using only basic data structures

Tags: performance, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a list of elements (database tables) that may have relations with each other, including themselves.

Let's assume I have table1, table2, table3 and table4. What I would like to create and use in a loop would be structure like this:

```
      |table1|table2|table3|table4||
table1| 1:1  |      |      |      ||
table2|      |  1:1 |      |      ||
table3|      |      | 1:1  |      ||
table4|      |      |      |  1:1 ||
```

Note that while it is not necessary to have 1:1 relations pre-filled, it is important for me to be able easily address any of these cells in a loop.

There will be `while(True)` loop that will iterate over and over again until the iteration without change occurs.

What I am currently struggling with is to find an efficient and pythonic way of doing this with basic python structures, while keeping decent performance and easy addressing.

Example of what I tried

```
tableNames = d.items(); # returns me this format ([(tableName, ['column1', 'column2']), ... ])
for tName in tableNames:
  # some sort of comparism and conditions resulting in whatever decision
  # for example, that I need to insert information about 
  # relation on [actualtable][table2]

  fancyStructure[actualtable][table2] = "1:N";
```

Is it a good idea to use dictionary? Respectively dictionary of dictionaries? What is the best way?

And is it okay to pre-initialize that dictionary to the values that I will change in time? Note that this script will work with millions or even billions of records.

## EDIT:

Input:

```
dict([('tableName', ['columnName', 'columnName2']), ('tableName2', ['columnName', 'columnName2'])])
```

Expected output:

```
tableName : tableName [relation], 
tableName : tableName2[relation], 
tableName2 : tableName[relation], 
tableName2 : tableName2[relation]
```

Relations will be linked to both of mentioned tables separated by colon and at the beginning there will be no value, or empty.

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: Please don't troll on SO. Your profile says: "professional troll". It's not very nice to waste other people's time by asking troll questions like these :/

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Sorry, that is not meant as a trolling and I edit the profile right away. I know that what is on expected output is a dictionary. What am I trying to find out is if it is a suitable solution for high amount of records/lines of input to process. Eventually if there is a better to way to do this.